# RegExp replace one of 3 options with the option found but in reverse

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I want to replace in a given text
if there is bx replace with xb
if there is ux replacel with xu
if there is sx replacel with xs
there are a lot of options, in all the options I want to revese the order of what was found. (the x has to be in before a given array of chars)
can it be written in one expretion.
I want to use it in Adobe Air AS3

```
lookFor = / \u05BC\u05BD | \u05C1\u05BD /
```

`replaceWith = \u05BD ???`  (it depends on what was found)
txt.replace(lookfor,replaceWith);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ActionScript/JavaScript the [`String.replace()` function](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#replace()) can take a function as your `replaceWith` argument.

Using capturing groups and the global flag you can find each group of characters and reverse them in the passed function:

```
lookFor = /(\u05BC\u05BD)|(\u05C1\u05C2)/g;

var reversedString: String = myString.replace(lookFor, function(str){
    return str.split('').reverse().join('');
});
```

NOTE: I've edited your RegExp to remove the spaces around the characters, I don't know how important they are for your search. You might want to consider using boundary `\b(\u05BC\u05BD)\b` matches instead of spaces, but it depends on what you're trying to match.

Comment: Great! Thanks, I didn't know you can use a function.